# Cannot read properties of created ref with createRef()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my calendar component:

```
export default class DemoApp extends React.Component {

  today = new Date();
  calendarRef = createRef();

....
```

I have a render function:

```
render() {
    const workMin = this.state.hours.map(item => item.startTime).sort().shift();
    const workMax = this.state.hours.map(item => item.endTime).sort().pop();
    this.getDateResult();
    return (
      <div className='demo-app'>
        {this.renderSidebar()}
        <div className='demo-app-main'>
          <FullCalendar
            ref={this.calendarRef}
            plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
            headerToolbar={{
              left: 'prev,next today',
              center: 'title'
            }}
            locale="hr"
            initialView='timeGridWeek'
            editable={true}
            selectable={true}
            selectMirror={true}
            dayMaxEvents={true}
            weekends={this.state.weekendsVisible}
            initialEvents={INITIAL_EVENTS}
            select={this.handleDateSelect}
            eventContent={renderEventContent}
            eventClick={this.handleEventClick}
            eventsSet={this.handleEvents}
            eventStartEditable={false}
            slotMinTime={workMin}
            slotMaxTime={workMax}
            validRange={{
              start: this.today
            }}
            events={this.state.morningBgEvent}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

And this is my function:

```
getDateResult() {
    const calendarApi = this.calendarRef.current.getApi();
    console.log(calendarApi.activeStart);
  }
```

Error:

```
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getApi')
```

I just want to console.log the start day of next week view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Explanation:

Why get this error?

You define a `ref` for your calendar and passed it to the `FullCalendar` element which is correct so far. but you are getting the `calendarRef` value before assigning it to the `FullCalendar`.

```
this.getDateResult();         // getting ref before assinging
return (
  <div className='demo-app'>
    {this.renderSidebar()}
    <div className='demo-app-main'>
      <FullCalendar
        ref={this.calendarRef}  // assigning ref
```

Using `componentDidMount` will ensure you the `FullCalendar` get its `ref` and then calls the `getDateResult` method properly.

##### The Solution:

Try to call your `getDateResult` inside of react life cycle method. for example, if you want to get the result on the initial phase, call the `getDateResult` method inside of a `componentDidMount`.

```
componentDidMount() {
   getDateResult()
}
```

Also, with functional component structure with hooks:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getDateResult()
}, [])
```